# Is it possible to have a dual-headed console?

Tags: nvidia, multi-monitor, proprietary-drivers

I'm running Arch Linux with proprietary nvidia driver and two monitors. I do not have a GUI installed on this machine. I want to take advantage of both monitors. How?

I know it is possible with the nouveau driver (it just works). But after installing the proprietary nvidia driver I can't seem to get it to work.

I found this old topic, but not much else:

Is it possible to have a dual-headed console? | Linux.com
http://www.linux.com/learn/answers/view/117-is-it-possible-to-have-a-dual-headed-console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proprietary NVIDIA driver does not support framebuffer consoles.

Here's [another relevant thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=117576).